# ASP.NET webcontrols render wrong in different culture settings

Tags: asp.net, globalization, cultureinfo, asp.net-webcontrol, currentuiculture

I have a self defined web control.

Some code in a loop:

```
double cellHeight = 12.34;
Label dcell = new Label();
dcell.Style["height"] = cellHeight  + "pt";
dcell.Text = cellHeight;
```

If I use `CultureInfo("cs-CZ")`

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");
```

after render, the html came out

```
<span style="height:11,75pt">11,75</span>
```

actually what I expected  is:

```
<span style="height:11.75pt">11,75</span>
```

`height:11,75pt` is totally wrong when rendered in browser, actually the browser does not consider `11,75pt` as `11.75pt`.

However I need to keep the text field displayed based on culture info: the text field displays `11,75` that is correct.

So this is the problem - how can I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert double to string properly, for example:

```
dcell.Style["height"] = cellHeight.ToString("F", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("eu-ES")) + "pt";
```

Or like this:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
dcell.Style["height"] = cellHeight.ToString(nfi) + "pt";
```

Comment: one more: eg .  double widthd=59.25;
                dcell.Width= new Unit(widthd, UnitType.Point) ;     then the rendered html is also width  59,25pt ,how to avoid it ,seems Unit classes rendered the value by culture info.but actually it no need.